# Upgrade to Java 11: -Djava.endorsed.dirs not supported

Tags: java, gradle, java-11

I want to upgrade a Java 8 Spring Boot project to Java 11. It uses Gradle 4.9(wrapper). I am using Intellij 2019.1 Community version.

After downloading Java 11, when I run `gradle test`, I see this error:

> -Djava.endorsed.dirs ..... is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.

So, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did these things to make it work:

- *Upgrade Intellij IDEA to 2019.2.4 Community*. It seems that it is using the Java option `-Djava.endorsed.dirs`. Because with Gradle 5.4, I can already run the tests in terminal by `gradle test`. It is only the Intellij run failing.

Upgrade Gradle to 6 may not be related; with `5.4.0` it can still work.

---

In order for this to work in Gitlab pipeline, you have to change

- `.gitlab-ci.yml`: `image: openjdk:11.0.1-jdk-slim`
- `Dockerfile`: `FROM gradle:jdk11-slim as builder`

to change docker image version.